# Magento 2: remove the category image and description from the corresponding XML file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, category-view

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I need to eliminate the category **image and description**, more exactly the `<div class="category-view"><!-- More code here --></div>` element from the category page.

The file to edit, if I am not wrong, is `app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`.

What is the piece of code I have to edit in order to eliminate the category image and description?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding below code in your

> app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: You seem like a very knowledgeable person when it comes to Magento. Will you be kind enough to answer the topic **[Assign all products in a category to all it's ancestor categories automatically, in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208650/assign-all-products-in-a-category-to-all-its-ancestor-categories-automatically)**? I am looking for a programming solution, not a dashboard one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the block that contains both of them this by adding `remove="true"` to the columns.top element.

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top" remove="true">
     <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
     </container>
</referenceContainer>
```